# Angular-cli v1.0.0 rc0 - VS Code not able to find name HTMLElement

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I have installed angular-cli 1.0.0-rc0 with node 7.6.0

This is what I get if I run `ng -v`

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
node: 7.6.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.8
@angular/compiler: 2.4.8
@angular/core: 2.4.8
@angular/forms: 2.4.8
@angular/http: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.8
@angular/router: 3.4.8
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.8
```

I scaffold now my first app via `ng new my-app` and I open the code using **VS Code 1.9.1**

Now, with my surprise, if I open *app.component.ts* file and try to define an HTML element (this is just an example) I get the following error (*cannot find name 'HTMLElement'*)

[image: Error in VS Code]

I see also that there is no *tsconfig.json* in the src folder (as I was used to see) rather there are *tsconfig.app.json* and *tsconfig.spec.json* while *tsconfig.json* has been put in the root directory of the project. The *tsconfig.*.** files are the default ones created by angular-cli.

Any hint about what is going wrong?

**SOLUTION**

In an Angular University blog (https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular-rxjs-reactive-patterns-what-reactive-properties-do-browser-events-have#comment-3179923151) I was pointed to the solution by **IndyGoodWill**.

I have to add *"dom"* in the *"lib"* array of *tsconfig.json* in the root directory of the project.
So, the default tsconfig.json (i.e. the file generated by `ng new` command) has

```
"lib": [
  "es2016"
]
```

and this creates the problem.

The problem gets solved with the following configuration

```
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
]
```

Now I realise that I have not clear the different roles of *tsconfig.json* in the project root directory and the *tsconfig.app.json* in the *src* directory.

Plus probably the second configuration should be the default one created by the `ng new` command.

Comment: Do you have imported 'HTMLElement' class in app.component.ts ?

Comment: I would not expect to have to declare it. If I do the same thing with previous versions of angular-cli I can use HTMLElement without having to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `typeRoots` to your `src/tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Will highlight it separately:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
```

Also, it looks like a good idea to remove `"types": [],` don't know why - but in this case I stop seeing `Cannot find name '$'` (Yes, I have to use Jquery in my project due to third-party plugin dependencies)

Comment: I apply the changes but this does not solve my problem

Comment: If I use angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.31 to scaffold a project and then I open the project with VS Code 1.9.1 I see that HTMLElement type definition is found in /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts . Unfortunately this does not happen if I use angular-cli 1.0.0 rc0

Comment: In addition to what I wrote above, you have to follow migration guide: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc.0-update